# Reload on HTML changes in webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to wrap my head around webpack and how it processes resources.

Here's my project structure:

```
/dist
  (files that can be pushed to server)
/src
  /styles
    s.less
  /js
    main.js
    a.js
  /img
    splash.png
  profile.html
entry.js (webpack entry file)
```

#### What I'm trying to do:

- LESS files are compiled to CSS and put into bundle along with JS
- Images are either copied `/src/img -> /dist/img` with their original names (good for big images) or base64'd and put into bundle (good for icons)
- htmls are copied `/src/ -> /dist/` with their original names
- every time I change html or anything in the styles or js, it does above steps and reloads page in browser

Basically I need to be able to see current state of application without ever touching the browser window

#### What i've tried

I ran

- `webpack-dev-server --content-base /dist  --hot-loading` (with and without `--hot-loading`), but this doesn't reload on CSS/LESS changes
- above along with `webpack --watch`, this solved CSS reloading, but I still need to copy html and images to /dist manually
- above two along with gulp task that watches html and images and copies them to dist. This solved copying problem, but it doesn't notify `webpack-dev-server` of changes so I need to F5 each time I change HTML; it defeats the whole purpose of hot reloading.
- I tried adding `file-loader` but this doesn't work for HTML since it produces JS script that requires html file

Here's my entry.js

```
require("./src/js/main");
require("./src/css/s.less");
```

And webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'/dist/js'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $ : "jquery",
            jQuery : "jquery",
            "window.jQuery" : "jquery",
            "root.jQuery" : "jquery"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: "style!raw!less"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

---

Is there a way to solve this using webpack only?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your output.path `/dist/js` is not matching with `--content-base /dist` [root directory of webpack-dev-server].

You can either try changing the output.path to `/dist` and then link the bundled output js in html or change the content base to `/dist/js`

Here is the link for your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47658586/1681972