# Webpack dev server cannot get `http://localhost/8080/bundle.js`

Tags: webpack-dev-server

Given this config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
    // hot: true,
  } 
}
```

Why won't webpack-dev-server server my app properly?  I have 0% understanding of localhost, vs localhost/webpack-dev-server, vs publicPath, vs contentBase, etc..  I know all of these paths, and configuration keys are important to setting up my project properly but despite hours of reading about them, they remain as confusing as when I started.

If I go to `localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server` I see `Get http://localhost:8080/bundle.js` net:ERR_ABORTED` in the console.

Comment: Me too. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

Below are simple and straight forward rules for webpack & webpack-dev-server :

1. **output.path** : It needs to be an [absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166492/getting-error-output-path-needs-to-be-an-absolute-path-or) or `/`. You can get it easily using `path.join`
2. **output.filename** : This needs to be the name of output file without any extra file path.
3. **devServer.contentBase** : It is the physical location on the disk which is served as the root directory of webpack-dev-server when you open `http://localhost:8080`

By convention, we keep both `output.path` and `devServer.contentBase` same. 
The tricky part is when you run `webpack` cmd, it generates the physical `bundle.js` file.

But when you run `webpack-dev-server`, **NO PHYSICAL OUTPUT** file is generated, rather it keeps the generated output in memory to avoid File-Write operate which in turn helps in faster development/debugging cycle.

So any change you make in `src.js or main.js` file, it will generate the output but won't write that to disk and wepack-dev-server reads that directly from the memory.

4. **output.publicPath** : This is used by webpack, webpack-dev-server & other plug-in to generate the output or serve the generated bundle.
   The default value is `/`.

> It is **VIRTUAL PATH** and need not be present on the physical
>   disk. Example : final application name if multiple apps are
>   hosted on the same server like `/app1`, `/app2`, or some external CDN path
>   `/CDN-Path`.
>
> It is also helpful for React-Router `<BrowserRouter basename='/app1'>`

Now to refer the bundle output file that is generated & kept in the memory , you need to append the `output.publicPath` i.e. `Virtual Path` in the browser's URL.

The final URL for webpack-dev-server will be :
**`http://localhost:8080/<output.publicPath>/<output.filename>`**

In your case, either you change the 
`publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')`
to
`publicPath: '/dist'` if it contains any spaces.
You can check it by printing the value of `path.join(__dirname, 'dist')` which returns the absolve path [different on MacOS & Window system].

`http://localhost:8080/dist/bundle.js`

If you want to dig further deeper, then here is the URL

https://medium.com/p/webpack-understanding-the-publicpath-mystery-aeb96d9effb1

Comment: Thanks man, helpful info 
adding below code saved me
    ```publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),```